# How do I create a event that fires up every time a new element is added to ArrayList

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to create an method that fires up every time a new message is added to the groupchat arraylist.
Pseudo code:

```
public void listenForChange(){
   while(true){
        if(new message is added to the groupchat){
             System.out.println(print the last added message);
        }
   }
 }
```

What I have tried, but doesn't work:

```
public class Groupe{
   ArrayList<String> groupechat;
   int liveChange;

 public void listenForChange() {
    while(true){
        if (groupchat.size() > liveChange){
            liveChange= gruppenchat.size();
            System.out.println(gruppenchat.get(liveChange-1));
        }
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
public class testGruppen extends Thread {
Gruppe gruppe;


public TestGroup(){
    gruppe= new Gruppe("Monday");
}

public void run() {
    System.out.println("listen");
    gruppe.listenForChange();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    testGruppen test = new testGruppen();
    test.start();
    test.gruppe.write("1"); // write just adds a new String to groupchat
    test.gruppe.write("2");
    test.gruppe.write("3");
    test.gruppe.write("4");

}
```

}

Output: `4` instead of `1\n 2\n 3\n 4\n`

Comment: Don't use a wasteful `while (true)` loop with polling, but instead use a call-back notification system such as by giving the class holding the ArrayList PropertyChangeSupport, allowing property change listeners to be added to it, and in the public method that updates the array list, notify all listeners of changes.

Comment: I don't understand how to do this. Could you give me a small example? @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: Take a look at `Observer` design pattern.

Comment: You have a mismatch. (Maybe by mistake.) In class `testGruppen` you have this class data member: `Gruppe gruppe;` But you have not provided code for class `Gruppe`. You have provided code for class `Groupe`.

Comment: Example given -- see answer

Answer (score 1):

What about using decorator:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    List<Integer> group = new FireEventListDecorator<>(new ArrayList<>());
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        group.add(i);
}

public static class FireEventListDecorator<E> extends AbstractList<E> {

    private final List<E> delegate;

    public FireEventListDecorator(List<E> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int index, E element) {
        delegate.add(index, element);
        fireEvent(element);
    }

    @Override
    public E get(int index) {
        return delegate.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return delegate.size();
    }

    private void fireEvent(E element) {
        System.out.println("add: " + element);
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd need to create an interface to allow listening to the events though.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid a CPU wasteful `while (true)` loop with polling, use a call-back method via an observer/listener pattern. One way to do this is to give your class that holds the ArrayList a `PropertyChangeSupport` instance, allow it to accept listeners, and then in the method that changes the ArrayList, notify listeners.

e.g.,

```
public class Group {
    // property listened to: ADD_TEXT
    public static final String ADD_TEXT = "add text";

    // the support object
    private PropertyChangeSupport support = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    private List<String> chatText = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        support.addPropertyChangeListener(ADD_TEXT, listener);
    }

    public void addText(String text) {
        String oldValue = "";
        String newValue = text;
        chatText.add(text + "\n");

        // notify listeners
        support.firePropertyChange(ADD_TEXT, oldValue, newValue);
    }
}
```

And then it can be used like so:

```
public class TestGroupChat {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Group group = new Group();
        group.addPropertyChangeListener(new GroupListener());
        final String[] texts = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"};

        new Thread(() -> {
            for (String text : texts) {
                group.addText(text);
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        }) .start();
    }

    private static class GroupListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            // call back method that is called any time the listened-to
            // property has been changed
            System.out.println("Notification: "+ evt.getNewValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [LinkedBlockingQueue class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html).
This class is useful when you want to wake up a thread when a new element is added to a queue. In the example below, everytime you add a new message to the queue, the thread will print the message and wait for the next message.

```
public class Foo extends Thread {

    LinkedBlockingQueue<String> messagesQueue;

    public Foo(LinkedBlockingQueue<String> messagesQueue) {
        this.messagesQueue = messagesQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public voir run() {
        while(true) {
            String message = messagesQueue.take();
           //The thread will sleep until there is a new message in the queue.
           System.out.println(message);
        }
    }

}
```